# Power for LEGO Creator Expert Roller Coaster (10261)

Tags: powered-up

In order to power the Creator Expert Roller Coaster (10261) can the 'Power Up' components Technic XL Motor (88014) and Technic Hub (88012) be substituted for 'Power Functions' components M Motor (8883) and AAA Battery Box (88000) which have both been discontinued?  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Powered Up is the replacement for Power Functions. However, Powered Up requires a smart device (smartphone/tablet) to control the hubs.

Used Power Functions parts are also available for sale on sites such as Bricklink, Brick Owl and Ebay.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback David which reassures me somewhat.  I am still concerned about whether the PU components that I have are adequately compatible with the roller coaster.  I am unsure whether the relative power will work the same way that the PF components would have.  I am worried that it may be too powerful and drive the cars off the track or too weak to get them up the hill.  May just have to resort to used PF parts as you suggested.  Any further thoughts appreciated.

Comment: There is a nice comparison of LEGO motor speeds and torques at https://philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm. And you can always add gears too.

Comment: They've introduced a Powered Up battery box this year, [88015](https://brickset.com/sets/88015-1/Powered-Up-Battery-Box), that works on its own and doesn't require Bluetooth, but I don't know if it's widely available.

Comment: The battery box hasn't been released yet. It was part of the 42113 Bell-Boeing V-22 Osprey set that was canceled.

Comment: Just noticed on Brickset, that battery box from 421133 Bell-Boeing V-22 Osprey - set # 88015 - HAS been released by LEGO and is available for purchase S@H.

Comment: Yeah, just saw the news today after I commented yesterday :-)